# SIP over websockets to true SIP

Tags: websocket, sip, webrtc, sip-server

I'm trying to implement a sip server for connecting to from an `HTML` sip client(made using sipml5). During my research into doing this I've come across sip over web-sockets which might be useful to me, however, I am unsure if a user agent connecting through sip over `web-sockets` to a compatible server would then be able to successfully make a call to some one using an incompatible server(i.e. calling from SIP over `web-sockets` to true SIP).

I know `webrtc2sip` can be used for connecting to legacy networks but I would rather avoid using another proxy if at all possible. So, is it possible to connect to a compatible `SIP` server using `SIP` over `web-sockets` then make a call from this user agent to another that does not support `SIP` over `web-sockets` without using a `gateway`?

Comment: You could use a SIP server that supports both traditional SIP (over TCP/UDP) and WebSockets to implement a gateway function. An example enabling technology would be Mobicents SIP Servlets (see https://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/wiki/Welcome?tm=6).

Comment: Would making a gateway be as simple as just connecting the user agents though a proxy that supports both or would certain headers need to patched/media encoded/etc.?

Comment: The answer to this depends on the interoperability of your endpoints (sipml5 and some other unspecified SIP UAs). To be clear, you would need to implement a proxy in Mobicents SIP Servlets. The gateway function has to be done *somewhere*, after all.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, SIP over Websockets is a draft, not specification. And I do not know many SIP vendors who support this draft.

Possible solution is truly websocket-SIP gateway. For example Flashphoner Web Call Server is implemented as a gateway which works through websockets with browser and works via SIP(TCP and UDP) with SIP servers. Therefore it is compatible with any server that supports RFC3261 - standard SIP specification.

Brief signaling scheme is:

**Browser - [Websockets] - Web Call Server - [SIP TCP, UDP] - any SIP Server**

Brief streaming scheme:

**Browser - [WebRTC = SRTP, DTLS, ICE, STUN ] - Web Call Server - [RTP UDP] - any SIP/RTP Server**

Answer (score 1):

Mobicents `SIP` Servlets Example already provides a `B2BUA` Application taking care of that for you. The Media is peer to peer (or through a `TURN` Relay Server) but if you need to bridge to a Media Server, you can indeed patch the `SDP` Body to make the media of each party go through the Media Server (pending it supports Media related codecs from WebRTC, `DTLS-SRTP` etc) to add conferencing, recording type of capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way is to use kamailio as it understands both sip and ws sip .

when you say "implementing a sip server " is it a simple registrar or proxy server or you want cal control logic / presence other features ?

In all cases kamailio fulfills all requirements , plus it is opensource .